# Why does this code not compile in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Why does this piece not compile in the following example?

"`|| this.greeting != "test2"`"

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    setGreeting(g) {
        this.greeting = g;
    }
    test() {
        if(this.greeting != "test" || this.greeting != "test2"){ 
            //this.greeting cound still be test3
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(this.greeting%20!%3D%20%22test%22%20%7C%7C%20this.greeting%20!%3D%20%22test2%22)%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fthis.greeting%20cound%20still%20be%20dsfdsfakj%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B)

Comment: Seems like a bug in the interpreter, I change the operator to `&&` and the error went away, either way the JavaScript is being generated.

Comment: It is great that typescript picks this up and flags the error, but with a little more thought the "Operator cannot be applied" error for two literal types with a common base could be replaced with a more meaningful message along the lines "condition is always true" (or "can never be true)" which would reduce the sort of confusion that led to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually a valid error, and prevented you from making a mistake.

```
if (this.greeting != "test" || this.greeting != "test2") {
```

Since you're using `||`, the second condition *will not be executed* unless `this.greeting == 'test'`.
Now, typescript is smart enough to automatically type `this.greeting` as `'test'` when it enters the second conditional block.

Clearly, `'test' != 'test2'` will never be false, and it's probably a mistake to check for that condition, since your entire `if` statement will *always* return true.

You probably wanted to write:

```
if (this.greeting != "test" && this.greeting != "test2") {
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time you have reached the `|| this.greeting != "test2"` part, the compiler knows for certain that `this.greeting` **must** be `"test"`, and therefore it narrows the type of `this.greeting` to the literal type `"test"`, which cannot be compared to `"test2"`.